# A gift that kept the king in line

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I've been searching for some time for a short color webcomic with relatively simple illustrations I had read maybe a year ago.

It concerned a king in a fable who desired a gift that would keep his spirits up, yet not a trifle that he would eventually grow bored with, or cause him to become overweening. The king offers grand rewards, etc.

The king naturally finds comers from the whole kingdom, but it's a small child who finally brings him something that does more than satisfy him.

It's **not** a ring reading "this too shall pass." That's an older story I can't recall the name of right now.

> The child had handed him a piece of parchment, upon which was written:
>  "You are not as ______ as you think you are."

Comment: I know it's probably not what you're looking for, but this totally reminds me of [The Alligator King](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVDUYJo3CjU). :D

Comment: Any idea of how old this webcomic is and/or where you might have read it? Art style? Color?

Comment: Edited with some more detail.